# qTip Jquery - Tool Tip Handling Webdriver using java

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

have an Text box control, while entered an invalid data its shown an Tool tip message (using qTip Jquery)

let please help how to get the Tool tip message with Web Driver using Java

below are the Html Code

```
<div class="ctrl-column">
<input id="txtEmail" class="input-txt" type="text" onpaste="return false" oncopy="return false" maxlength="160" data-bind="value: Email,qtipValMessage:Email" title="Please enter the email" data-orig-title="">
</div>
```

then passing an Invalid Entry in that txtEmail Field, now the code look like this

```
<div class="ctrl-column">
<input id="txtEmail" class="input-txt ErrorControl" type="text" onpaste="return false" oncopy="return false" maxlength="160" data-bind="value: Email,qtipValMessage:Email" title="" data-orig-title="" data-hasqtip="3" oldtitle="Please enter valid email">
</div>
```

so i want to capture the oldtitle Attribute value (i.e `Please enter valid email`)

below is my java code

```
String ValidationMessage = driver.findElement(
                By.cssSelector("input#txtEmail")).getAttribute("oldtitle");
```

while executing its always return `null` value

Please help me how can collect the validation message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this !

```
String ValidationMessage = driver.findElement(
            By.cssSelector("#txtEmail.input-txt.ErrorControl")).getAttribute("oldtitle");
```